Sum of node depths for balanced binary tree
How can I calculate the sum of all node depth for balanced binary tree based on count of nodes?

If you are looking for 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, ... sequence it is  https://oeis.org/A001855 Closed formula is "Let n = 2^(k-1) + g, 0 <= g <= 2^(k-1); then a(n) = 1 + n*k - 2^k"

Some examples of what you expect for which depth would be nice.

If it’s completely balanced, the formula would be
(tree_height - 1) * 2^(tree_height + 1) + 2

where root is at depth 0.

Do you mean height?

@trincot sure, we could call it “height.” I used OP’s language.

OK, but the OP spoke of a node's depth. But in your formula there is no reference to a node.

@trincot edited, thanks!
